# Angular matInput not updating component property with two-way binding in Jasmine unit test

Tags: angular, angular-material, jasmine

I have a `matInput` used to update a component property:

```html
<input matInput [(ngModel)]="componentProperty" />
<div>componentProperty value is: {{ componentProperty }}</div>
```

This works when I play with it: the displayed `componentProperty` value matches what I put in the box.

However, the unit test I wrote for this doesn't work:

```js
    it('should update componentProperty to match input box value', async () => {
        const inputHarness = await loader.getHarness(
            MatInputHarness
        );
        const testValue = 'hello';

        expect(component.componentProperty).toEqual('');
        await inputHarness.setValue(testValue);
        expect(component.componentProperty).toEqual(testValue);
    });
```

This fails with `Expected '' to equal 'hello'.` What gives?

Answer (score 1):

The clue here is the console error message: `Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.`

The problem was in the setup of the tests: we weren't importing the right modules. We needed to add to our test setup:

```js
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,
  ],
  ...
});
```

The way to understand the test failure was: we weren't actually binding the input box to the component property, because the test framework didn't know what `matInput` was, and therefore didn't know what to do with `ngModel`. We needed to tell it how to handle `matInput` by importing the relevant modules.